# "No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities." when running on simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, visual-studio, xamarin, keychain

Allo

I am trying to use the iOS Keychain in Xamarin but I was getting Error 34018. After some googling I added Entitlements.plist and added that to the custom entitlements in iOS Bundle Signing in the project properties but now I'm getting the "No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS signing identities." error. I am trying to run the app in the simulator and I thought running in a simulator didn't require a provisioning profile. Why does adding Entitlements.plist cause this error and how can I get past it?

Thanks!

Comment: Beware: following the instructions on http://thatcodingguy.com/fixing-xamarin-ios-error-no-installed-provisioning-profiles-match/ will not fix it for current versions: as soon as you use the Xamarin Auth Store Keychain you will get exceptions. So you _do_ need to set up a provisioning profile as described by @SushiHangover.
Note that it is possible to share a single provisioning profile between multiple developers so if you are part of a team that has one set up you can get the group manager to add you to it on the apple developer site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using any type of iOS capabilities (an iOS app service) requires a iOS provisioning profile and that is totally ***independent*** on if you are targeting a physical iDevice **or** the iOS simulator.

> To use capabilities, the app must have a valid provisioning profile that contains an App ID with the correct service enabled

Thus to use the `Keychain`, an iOS app service, you have to have a valid provisioning profile. A free provisioning profile can be used, but you must register your app's `Bundle Identifier` via Xcode with a physical device attached so you can then in turn assign the appropriate values in your `Entitlements.plist` and build the app with Xamarin using that provisioning profile. You can then debug the app on a physical device or the simulator.

- [iOS Free Provisioning](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/device_provisioning/free-provisioning/)